# how to distinguish photos taken with different phones?

Tags: smartphone

i'm trying to know how to distinguish same photos taken with different phones.
i have 6 pictures from 6 different mobile phones.
how can i understand which picture belong to which phone?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is this an academic interest, or research interest? What is the source of the photos (that is, did they come from social media, or maybe a Google Images search)? Is the EXIF data present in all of the images? Or are you asking if it's possible to identify the camera taking the pictures strictly by analyzing the images themselves, by inferring optical properties, field of view, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it with Exif metadata.
Install photo viewer which shows Exif and distinguish it by tag "camera model".

Comment: Unless the photos were uploaded to Facebook (or a lot of other photo providers). Unless someone is trying to break your algorithm. Unless you have two people who both use an iPhone 6S. etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Why the downvote? For most cases this should do the trick. The OP did not mention that intentional abuse should be detected.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I think you left out Descartes evil demon.

Comment: I have to agree with Philip. If this is a simple case of someone trying to remember which of their 6 phones they used to take which photo, then Exif data can help. But if it's part of a more complex puzzle, then Exif may not be the solution. Indeed, there may not be a solution. But I would suggest more info is needed.

Comment: there may be other tags suitable to distinguish devices, too. Eg. some record a device number, or a software version.

Answer (score -3):

Go to `Properties > Details`.

You will get all the basic info.

You don't need exif for this.

Comment: This 1) assumes you're using a specific piece of software and 2) has all the problems of Przyczajona_Dzika_Świnia's answers - it's still reading the EXIF data, even if it doesn't present it that way.

Comment: @PhilipKendall 1) What do you mean by specific piece of software? 2) I'm not replying to Przyczajona_Dzika_Świnia comment. I'm answering to the question so I'm not interested in extra data (EXIF).

Comment: 1) I *think* you're assuming that the poster is using Windows Explorer. Not everybody does, you know. 2) The "basic info" you're talking about there *is* part of the EXIF data. If you strip the EXIF data from an image, you won't see anything there anymore.

Comment: @PhilipKendall 1) If I'm not wrong whether you use Windows, Mac or Linux you will get this basic info everywhere. 2) In case of deletion of exif data, you will get nothing whether you follow my process of use some forensic software. user68067 just wants to know the `Camera Maker` or `Camera Model`, using exif here is like traveling in rocket wen you have a domestic plane service. Sorry if I'm too harsh.